# Why vpn configuration is disappeared on ununtu

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, vpn, openvpn, vpnc

I am not able to create vpn connection, I have created many times before. but i installed a fresh ubuntu and now I cannot create a vpn connection. I want to connect to a server.

I installed the followings:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager-gnome network-manager network-manager-openvpn-gnome network-manager-openvpn openvpn
```

I am not able to create a vpn connection because the save is grayed out. 
and I do not see VPN configuration on network menu. 
even when I chose vpn/openvpn the menu has `gateway` after entering that the save is deactive. what is `authentication type` such as `certificate LTS`?

Please please help me with this. Thanks a lot